# Django Page not rendered and not visible

Tags: html, django, render

I have cloned a project from Git on my laptop. After the installation of all the requirements, while running the server I found out that a page is not rendered correctly, therefore I can't see the body. More precisely the body is not shown on the webpage. Does anyone know why this happened?
This is the code:

```
{% block content %}
<section id="consultanta_totala">

<div class="pricing_div" id="consultanta">
        <div class="container" id="container_consultanta" >
            <div class="row" id="text1">

           <div class="col-xs-12 offset-xs-0 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1  risk_management">
            <br><br>

               <h4> Risk management </h4>
               <p> • Crearea structurii de securitate a firmei Dvs.</p>
               <p>• Verificarea antecedentelor penale ale angajatilor</p>
               <p>• Verificarea compatibilitatii angajatilor</p>
               <p>• Verificare loialitatii angajatilor</p>
               <p>• Norme interne de protectie a firmelor</p>
               <p>• Profiling</p>
           </div>
                <br>

            </div>
<br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xs-12 offset-xs-0 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1  verificare">

                <h4>Verificarea partenerilor de afaceri</h4>
                <p> Din punct de vedere al:</p>
                  <p>• Solvabilitatii si seriozitatii persoanei</p>
                  <p>• Corectitudinii obligatiilor contractuale</p>
                   <p>• Intentiilor reale si ale concurentei neloiale</p>

                    <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            </div>




        </div>
    </div>

</section>
{% include 'navbar_bottom.html' %}
{%  endblock %}
```

PS before posting the item on git it worked properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you haven't extended your base html, where is block content supposed to reside?

Answer (score 0):

I got the error because the page didn't had the {% load staticfiles %} variable. Thank you for your help!